# ShowOpenDialog not working on recent versions of electron-js

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new on electronjs and developing a small application that reads a json file and build a small html form and return the values entered by the user.
So I've developed small scripts in javascript that link to html 'button' tags to call dialogs so that a user can enter directories, files and save the final form. Everything works nicely... on electronjs "^3.1.13". But if I'm updating to a recent version of the lib ("^8.2.5"), then all my cool ShowOpenDialog don't work at all. Any clue of what happens?
Here is the script to open a folder if it helps:

```
{
 let myName = document.currentScript.getAttribute('name');
 const ipc       = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

 let  asyncBtn  = document.querySelector('#folder-selector-'+myName);
 let replyField = document.querySelector('#folder-selector-content-'+myName);
 let onButtonClick = function() {
     const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
     let dialogOptions = {
       title: "Choisir un dossier:",
       properties: ['openDirectory','promptToCreate'],
     };
     dialog.showOpenDialog(
         dialogOptions,
         fileNames => {
           if (fileNames === undefined) {
             console.log("No file selected");
           } else {
             console.log('file:', fileNames[0]);
             replyField.value = fileNames[0];
           }
     })
 };

 asyncBtn.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
```

}

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that the call to [dialog.showOpenDialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) has indeed been updated in recent versions of Electron, and returns a promise instead of making use of a callback function, there is another flaw in your updated code: reading the above-mentioned documentation page shows that `getCurrentWindow()` is *not* a method of `dialog`; it can be obtained from `remote` instead, so you have to add it explicitely:

```
 const { dialog, getCurrentWindow } = require('electron').remote;
```

then simply call it from inside `dialog.showOpenDialog`:

```
 dialog.showOpenDialog( getCurrentWindow(), dialogOptions).then(result => {
```

but this is an error you could have caught yourself by looking at the DevTools's console, which would display:

> TypeError: dialog.getCurrentWindow is not a function

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I need to use a proper developer environment for my javascript code now. I was editing on Xcode as I'm way more used to develop in C++ . I check these devtools and try not to bother more the community!

Answer (score 2):

Recent version of showOpenDialog receives two arguments: optional BrowserWindow, and options as second argument. It returns promise and not requires callback.
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/8-x-y/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options

So you need to change you callback logic to promises.

```
let onButtonClick = function() {
     const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
     let dialogOptions = {
       title: "Choisir un dossier:",
       properties: ['openDirectory','promptToCreate'],
     };
     dialog.showOpenDialog(
         dialogOptions
     ).then((fileNames)=>{
           if (fileNames === undefined) {
             console.log("No file selected");
           } else {
             console.log('file:', fileNames[0]);
             replyField.value = fileNames[0];
           }
     }).catch(err=>console.log('Handle Error',err))


 };

 asyncBtn.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue about the promises.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot Vladimir. So I've tried to update my code as explained, updating electron package to version 8.2.5 and modifying the script as you explained but it's not going any better. If I got it well, this code should be correct, but doesn't work on electron 8.2.5. Any error you still see on this?

```
 {
 let myName = document.currentScript.getAttribute('name');
 const ipc       = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

 let  asyncBtn  = document.querySelector('#folder-selector-'+myName);
 let replyField = document.querySelector('#folder-selector-content-'+myName);
 let onButtonClick = function() {
     const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

     let dialogOptions = {
       title: "Choisir un dossier:",
       properties: ['openDirectory','promptToCreate']
     };
     dialog.showOpenDialog( dialog.getCurrentWindow(), dialogOptions).then(result => {
     if(!result.canceled) {
          replyField.value = result.filePaths[0];
      }
     }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
     })
 };
 asyncBtn.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it. Apart from the most appreciated help I had, I missed 
            "webPreferences": {
              nodeIntegration: true
            }
in the main.js to make it work. 
The discovering of the Developer Tools were of great help as well :)

Now everything is fine again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use the edit option on your other Answer to add any additional information. Also please do not post "Thank you", but just the actual Answer.