# How do I use showOpenDialog withe Electron’s IPC?

Tags: electron, ipc, filedialog

I am learning to live without `remote` in my electron app. I have got to the point where I need to open a file from the renderer, which I understand required the main process to show the file dialog and send back the results.

In my `main.js`, I have the following:

```js
ipcMain.on('open-file',(event,data)=>{
    dialog.showOpenDialog(null, data, (filePaths) => {
        event.sender.send('open-file-paths', filePaths);
    });
});
```

In my render process, which I call `pager.js`, I have the following:

```js
ipcRenderer.send('open-file',{
    title: 'Title',
    defaultPath: localStorage.getItem('defaultPath')
});
ipcRenderer.on('open-file-paths',(event,data)=>{
    console.log(event);
    console.log(data);
});
```

The file open dialog works well enough, but I don’t know how to get the results. the `ipcRenderer.on('open-file-paths',…)` doesn’t get called, so that’s obviously not the right way to do it. I would like to get either the selected path(s) or a cancelled message.

How do I get the results for `showOpenDialog` in the render process?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I’ve got it.

Thanks to an answer in [ShowOpenDialog not working on recent versions of electron-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559718/showopendialog-not-working-on-recent-versions-of-electron-js#answer-61566377), I see that `showOpenDialog` now returns a promise, which means reworking the code in `main.js`. Here is a working solution:

```js
//  main.js
    ipcMain.on('open-file',(event,data)=>{
        dialog.showOpenDialog(null, data).then(filePaths => {
            event.sender.send('open-file-paths', filePaths);
        });
    });

//  pager.js (render)
    ipcRenderer.send('open-file',{
        title: 'Title',
        defaultPath: localStorage.getItem('defaultPath')
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('open-file-paths',(event,data)=>{
        console.log(`Canceled? ${data.canceled}`);
        console.log(`File Paths: ${data.filePaths.join(';')`);
    });
```

Comment: or you can use sync method `dialog.showOpenDialogSync([browserWindow, ]options)`
https://www.electronjs.org/ru/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogsyncbrowserwindow-options